# Why APK created by Android Studio is larger than APK created by Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk

My APK created by Eclipse is 900K, but by Android Studio is 1.62MB. The code is same. Why? In Eclipse, I add facebook-sdk.jar, google-analytics.jar and other jars to my libs. In Android Studio, the two build.gradle are as follows:

1. build.gradle in project

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```
2. build.gradle in module

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
       buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 21
       }

       buildTypes {
           release {
               shrinkResources true
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
           }
       }
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
       //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
       compile files('libs/stickylistheaders_lib.jar')
   }
   ```

Comment: Which apk did you build in each one? release or build?

Comment: release. I generate signed apk. If I choose debug type, the size of the apk is larger than 2MB.

Comment: You can always open the apks with winrar or a similar program to check which part of the apk is taking that much space

Comment: ok, I'll try.thank u!

Answer (score 1):

use this in `build.gradle` the problem is in gradle build

```
 buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

    }

}
```

Comment: But my buildType is release. I generate signed apk.

Comment: Configure the proguardFiles before generating signed apk.

Comment: The proguard-project.txt in my Eclipse project is same as the file in my Android Studio project. While if I generate the debug apk, the APK size is larger than 2MB.